# Абстрактный bean в Spring с помощью java configuration

Tags: spring, configuration

В книге Spring in Action есть пример, в котором спринг может управлять бином, созданном с помощью конструктора. Он выглядит так:

```
<bean id="pianist" class="com.springinaction.springidol.Instrumentalist" abstract="true">
  <property name="song" value="Chopsticks" />
  <property name="instrument">
      <bean class="com.springinaction.springidol.Piano" />
  </property>
</bean>
```

В то же время, в современных версиях Spring можно использовать Java для конфигурации. Что-то типа того:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@PropertySource("application.properties")
public class MainConfig
{
    @Bean
    public Instrumentalist Instrumentalist()
    {
        // внедрение
    }
}
```

Можно ли с помощью аннотаций пометить бин как абстрактный, т.е. чтобы зависимости внедрялись в экземпляр класса, созданный конструктором в коде, а не Spring'ом? На офиц. сайтах почему-то отсутствуют упоминания о таком

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Абстрактные бины в XML конфигурации нужны только для того, чтобы уменьшить кол-во одинаковой логики в инициализации производных бинов. В JavaConfig это не имеет смысла, т.к. вы можете избежать дублирования на уровне кода путем вынесения общей логики в отдельный метод.

Comment: На самом деле, это очередная попытка загрузить свойства @Value("${rest}") из .properties файла. Просто в связи с тем, что я использую GUI, построить приложение с DI затруднительно, а тут вроде написано, что можно создать экземпляр класса стандартно, конструктором, добавить @Configurable, подключить AOP(или что-то вроде того), и оно будет работать. Пока я пробую это сделать с xml конфигурацией, но пока безуспешно бьюсь с AOP - описанные в литературе Manning способы обозначены лишь парой строчек. Но если можно это сделать с Java Configuration, было бы неплохо